# Does the set given by $\{(\frac 1n)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ include $0$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Is there some sort of consensus on whether or not $$0 \in \{(\frac 1n)\}_{n=1}^\infty?$$

Comment: As others said, the answer is no. But, $0$ is the infimum (greatest lower bound) of this set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's not there. The only elements of that set are $\frac1n$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$. Since $0$ is not of the form $\frac1n$, it's not there.

Answer (score 1):

No. $0$ will be in the closure of the set if it is taken in the suitable topology in $\Bbb R$

Comment: Note $0$ may not be in the closure also if some topologies are conidered such as discrete topology

Comment: $0$ will be in the CLOSURE of the set, but not in the set itself.

Comment: Yeah on usual topology in $\Bbb R$. But not on discrete topology

Comment: No matter what the topology, $0$ will not be a member of the specified set.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I was just saying about the closure. Though it was not asked.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps some confusion arises from the notation $\{1/n\}_{n=1}^\infty$.  The index $n$ is a member of the set $\{1,2,3,4,\ldots\}$ in which each number is a finite integer.  There is no finite integer whose reciprocal is $0$.  Therefore $0$ is not a member of this set.  What I suspect sometimes causes confusion is the notation's use of the symbol "$\infty$", perhaps suggesting that something called $\infty$ occurs as one of the values of the index.  But it is actually intended only to indicate that the sequence $1,2,3,4,\ldots$ does not come to an end.